# Volume data does not fill when running a bamboo container on the server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am trying to run bamboo on server using docker containers. When i running on local machine work normally and volume save datas successfully. But when i run same docker compose file on server, volume data not save my datas.

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  bamboo:
    container_name: bamboo-server_test
    image: atlassian/bamboo-server
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/bamboo_test_vol:/var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo
    ports:
      - 8085:8085

volumes:
  bamboo_test_vol:
```

### Run this compose file on local machine

```
$ docker-compose up -d
  Creating network "test_default" with the default driver
  Creating volume "test_bamboo_test_vol" with default driver
  Creating bamboo-server_test ... done
$ docker ps
  CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
  916c98ca1a9d        atlassian/bamboo-server   "/entrypoint.sh"    24 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes       0.0.0.0:8085->8085/tcp, 54663/tcp   bamboo-server_test
$ ls
  docker-compose.yml    volumes
$ cd volumes/bamboo_test_vol/
$ ls
  bamboo.cfg.xml    logs
```

### localhost:8085

[image]

### Run this compose file on server

```
$ ssh <name>@<ip_address>
  password for <name>:
$ docker-compose up -d
  Creating network "test_default" with the default driver
  Creating volume "test_bamboo_test_vol" with default driver
  Creating bamboo-server_test ... done
$ docker ps
  CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND             CREATED            STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
  38b77e1b736f        atlassian/bamboo-server   "/entrypoint.sh"    12 seconds ago     Up 11 seconds       0.0.0.0:8085->8085/tcp, 54663/tcp   bamboo-server_test
$ ls
  docker-compose.yml  volumes
$ cd volumes/
$ cd bamboo_test_vol/
$ ls
$ # VOLUME PATH IS EMPTY
```

### server_ip:8085

[image]

I didn't have this problem when I tried the same process for jira-software. Why can't it work through the bamboo server even though I use the exact same compose file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I wanted to upgrade my Bamboo server instance with my mounted host volume for the bamboo-home directory.

The following was in my **docker-compose** file:

```
version: '2.2'

bamboo-server:
 image: atlassian/bamboo-server:${BAMBOO_VERSION}
 container_name: bamboo-server
 environment:
   TZ: 'Europe/Berlin'
 restart: always
 init: true
 volumes:
   - ./bamboo/bamboo-server/data:/var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo
 ports:
   - "8085:8085"
   - "54663:54663"
```

When i started with `docker-compose up -d bamboo-server`, the container never took the files from the host system. So I tried it first without docker-compose, following the instructions of [Atlassian Bamboo](https://hub.docker.com/r/atlassian/bamboo-server) with the following command:

```
docker run -v ./bamboo/bamboo-server/data:/var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo --name="bamboo-server" --init -d -p 54663:54663 -p 8085:8085 atlassian/bamboo-server:${BAMBOO_VERSION}
```

The following error message was displayed:

> docker: Error response from daemon: create ./bamboo/bamboo-server/data: "./bamboo/bamboo-server/data" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.

So I converted the error message and took the absolute path:

```
docker run -v /var/project/bamboo/bamboo-server/data:/var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo --name="bamboo-server" --init -d -p 54663:54663 -p 8085:8085 atlassian/bamboo-server:${BAMBOO_VERSION}
```

After the successful start, I switched to the docker container via SSH and all files were as usual in the docker directory.

I transferred the whole thing to the docker-compose file and took the absolute path in the volumes section. Subsequently it also worked with the docker-compose file.

My **docker-compose** file then looked like this:

```
[...]
 init: true
 volumes:
   - /var/project/bamboo/bamboo-server/data:/var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo
 ports:
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a containerized Bamboo Server is not supported for these reasons;

- Repository-stored Specs (RSS) are no longer processed in Docker by default. Running RSS in Docker was not possible because;
- there is no Docker capability added on the Bamboo server by default,
- the setup would require running Docker in Docker.

Comment: why do they have a bamboo-server docker image then? https://hub.docker.com/r/atlassian/bamboo-server/